# Dynamic Adding UILabel to UIView Then Editing

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

Let's say you want to add some text to a UIView. And to do this, you first click a button that brings up a textfield. This textfield is moveable on screen and can be placed anywhere. The user will input text into the field and click a save button. The textfield disappears and a UILabel is created and in its place with the text that was entered. Should the user wish to edit that text at a later time, they simply can touch it, the UILabel will be removed and a textfield will appear with the contents of the text. I have yet to implement the touch method for label.

Where would I begin with such a beast?

I have created a TextView that holds the UILabel in an Array along with its correct properties. it will run though the array and drawRect will pop out every label exactly where it is suppose to.

I am just afraid I am leaking memory or I am going about this completely wrong. Is there a tutorial or something out there that anyone knows of that would help point me in the right direction? Should TextView be a subclass of UILabel?

Here is my TextView.h

```
@interface TextManager : UIView 

- (void) addTextToView : (NSString *) s : (int)rx :(int) ry;
```

TextView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
          self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
       NSLog(@"Draw Rect Text Manager");
    // Drawing code
    Settings *mySettings = [Settings sharedSettings];

    if ([[mySettings returnTextArray] count] > 0) {
        [self.superview addSubview:[[mySettings returnTextArray] lastObject]];
    }

}

- (void) addTextToView : (NSString *) s : (int)rx :(int) ry {
    NSLog(@"Add Text to View");

    UIColor *tempColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    CGRect  tempRect = CGRectMake(rx, ry, 100, 100);

    UILabel *thisLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:tempRect];
    thisLabel.text = s;
    thisLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    thisLabel.textColor = tempColor;
    thisLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    thisLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (0);
    thisLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    thisLabel.tag = 1;

    [textArray addObject:thisLabel];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Check for leaks using instruments

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to swap labels and text fields to achieve the desired results. Use one `UITextField` inside a `UIView`:

```
@interface CSTextView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation CSTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];

        textField.placeholder = @"Your text here";
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

        [self setTextField:textField];
        [self addSubview:textField];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then, in your view controller, implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and add a gesture recognizer to the text view to handle the dragging, like so:

```
@interface CSViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *textView;

@end

@implementation CSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CSTextView *textView = [[CSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 60)];

    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1]];
    [[textView textField] setDelegate:self];

    [textView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]];

    [self setTextView:textView];
    [[self view] addSubview:textView];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Gesture recognizer

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:[self view]];

    if ([panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [[self textView] setFrame:CGRectOffset([[self textView] frame], translation.x, translation.y)];
    }

    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[self view]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Text field methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: If i add these to view, the last one that I add is the only one that I can move or go back and edit @cameron-spickert